M code for the equivalent of of Left (string, len(string)-11)
How to remove the last X characters from a string in a column?
I am trying to generate a list of user-friendly file names that are used in the generation of a Power Query table.  However when reading the list of m text commands, I did not see a straightforward approach for doing the the equivalent of:
 Text.left(#"previous table"{"Filename'}, Text.length(#"previous table"{"Filename'} - 11)

(based on my knowledge of Excel).
Since I saw my filenames have variable length to them but knew I always wanted to eliminate the last 11 characters, I thought maybe I could use Text.reverse(#"previous table"{"Filename'}) and then do a split at position 11 and just keep the right side of the split and then do another reversal.  However I don't know m syntax well enough yet and all I got was an error when I tried to do Text.Reverse
My m code:
let
    Source = Forecasting,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Source.Name", "Submitted Reports"}}),
    Custom1 = Text.Reverse(#"Renamed Columns"{{"Submitted Reports"}})
in
    Custom1

Example data when we get to the Renamed Columns step:
Submitted Reports
Bug Bunny 241008923443.xlsm
Daffy Duck 241130234521.xlsm
Wyle E. Cayote 240909124312.xlsm

Desired results:
Submitted Reports
Bug Bunny 241008
Daffy Duck 241130
Wyle E. Cayote 240909


Remove the file extension (if exists) and the last six characters:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    // Remove ".xlsm" if it exists
    RemoveExtension = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Submitted Reports", each if Text.EndsWith(_, ".xlsm") then Text.RemoveRange(_, Text.Length(_) - 5, 5) else _}}),
    CleanFilenames = Table.TransformColumns(RemoveExtension, {{"Submitted Reports", each Text.RemoveRange(_, Text.Length(_) - 5, 5)}})
in
    CleanFilenames

If you want to remove the last five characters knowing what they are (".xlsm"):
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    CleanFilenames = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Submitted Reports", each if Text.EndsWith(_, ".xlsm") then Text.RemoveRange(_, Text.Length(_) - 5, 5) else _}})
in
    CleanFilenames

or if you want to remove a four character file extenstion:
CleanFilenames = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Submitted Reports", each if Text.Middle(_, Text.Length(_) - 5, 1) = "." then Text.RemoveRange(_, Text.Length(_) - 5, 5) else _}})

or just remove the last five characters:
CleanFilenames = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Submitted Reports", each Text.RemoveRange(_, Text.Length(_) - 5, 5)}})


hrrrm close  the text.RemoveRange is looking like where I want to end up but I am also trying to remove the 6 characters before the . as well.  what does the _ mean?

_ stands for the cell content.  Let me just modify the code for you.

@ForwardEd - please see the addended answer

why is there a second 5 in the text.removeRange? Text.RemoveRange(_, Text.Length(_) - 5, 5)

I think I got it.  (text to be modified, starting point, amount to remove)
